# Gradle JavaFX - java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, build.gradle, executable-jar

A null pointer exception is generated when the program is built using Gradle & executed via below command (Note: program works fine if I click run from within IntelliJ IDE):

`java -jar main-1.0.jar`

I tried the solution provided in [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128652/location-is-required-in-javafx-with-gradle) which is similar to this case but it does not fix the issue.

I also tried the solution provided in [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266492/location-is-required-exception-when-loading-fxml-file) but even that does not fix the issue.

The Gradle script incorporates solution from my earlier query - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52868834/3127144)

The FXML file (Sample.fxml) is located in src/main/resources

Hope issue faced is clear & any pointers as to how this issue can be fixed ?

**Code**:

Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Sample.fxml"));
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(root);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'testJavaFx'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/resources"]
            includes = ["**/*.fxml"]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-base:11:win'
    compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:11:win'
    compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:11:win'
    compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:11:win'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileJava {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls',
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.fxml',
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.base',
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.graphics'
        ]
    }
}

run {
    doFirst {
        jvmArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls',
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.fxml',
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.base',
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.graphics'
        ]
    }
}

def jarPackage(String jarName, String className, artifactVersion) {
    if (artifactVersion == "" || artifactVersion == null) {
        artifactVersion = "1.0.0"
    }
    return tasks.create("jar${jarName}", Jar) {
        baseName = jarName
        version = artifactVersion

        String pkgName = className.substring(0, className.lastIndexOf("."))
        String pkgDir = pkgName.replaceAll("\\.", "/")
        String clazzName = className.substring( className.lastIndexOf(".") +1 )

        from(sourceSets.main.output) {
            include "$pkgDir//**"
        }

        from {
            configurations.compile.collect {
                it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
            }
        }

        manifest {
            attributes "Implementation-Title": "$clazzName",
                    "Implementation-Version": "$version",
                    "Main-Class": "$pkgName.$clazzName"
        }
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives jarPackage("Main", "pkg1.Main" , "1.0")
}
```

Comment: Did you inspect the jar to see if the FXML file was added to it?

Comment: I added - from(sourceSets.main.resources) {
            includes = ["**/*.*"]
        } This seems to have fixed the issue. Don't know if this is the right approach. This is added in the create task portion of the build script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this by removing the SourceSets (below repositories) & adding the below code in tasks.Create

```
from(sourceSets.main.resources) {
            includes = ["**/*.*"]
}
```